# Dynamics CRM 365 - How to open view filtered based on related record

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I've created a new entity called followups and have the following scenario where I need to add a button to the account detail form and from that button I need to open a view filtered that will show a list of all followups regarding that account, but I cannot find anywhere a way to do that kind of filter, is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [lookupObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility/lookupobjects) method, you can invoke this lookup functionality from a Ribbon button.

Example:

```
var lookupOptions = {
    defaultEntityType: "account",
    entityTypes: ["account"],
        allowMultiSelect: false,
        customFilters: ["%3Cfilter%20type%3D%22and%22%3E%3Ccondition%20attribute%3D%22name%22%20operator%3D%22eq%22%20value%3D%22test%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Ffilter%3E"],
    customFilterTypes: [""]
};

Xrm.Utility.lookupObjects(lookupOptions)
    .then(function(result){
    })
    .fail(function(error){
    });
```

[Read more](https://butenko.pro/2017/11/22/microsoft-dynamics-365-v9-0-lookupobjects-closer-look/)

Comment: Thank you Arun, but, it's not really a lookup since I need to open the view in a new window

Comment: @rafaetti actually this will open lookup popup only, you can leverage any view with filter.. read the link I shared.. also this: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/debajitcrm/archive/2018/06/04/open-lookup-dialog-programmatically-using-xrm-utility-dynamics-v9-0

Comment: Thanks Arun I'll look into it!